# RC.5 throws "Cannot find 'default' when lazy loading module with routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

tried to lazy load a module in an angular2 rc. app. This module contains routes itself. The app is trying to lazy load the module on clicking the route it is registered on but immediately throws

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'default' in './app/test/test.module'
```

Routes in app are defined like:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StartComponent },
  { path: 'route1', component: Route1Component },
  { path: 'test', loadChildren: './app/test/test.module'},
  { path: '**', component: StartComponent } //page not found
];
```

The TestModule contains following routes:

```
export const TestRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview' },
      { path: 'overview', component: TestOverviewComponent },
      { path: 'moredata', component: MoreDataComponent }
];
```

I removed redirectTo and pointed the default route to a real component without luck. 
Also tried defining routes with children like

```
export const AdminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test', component: TestComponent,
    children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview' },
          { path: 'overview', component: TestOverviewComponent },
          { path: 'moredata', component: MoreDataComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

with same result.

Any hints what might be wrong? Loading the module eagerly works as intended.

Regards

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to add the exported class name of your module to the loadChildren string, like

```
{ path: 'test', loadChildren: './app/test/test.module'},
```

change to

```
{ path: 'test', loadChildren: './app/test/test.module#TestModule'},
```

as stated in official documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> If we look closer at the loadChildren string, we can see that it maps
>   directly to our crisis-center.module file where we previously built
>   out our Crisis Center feature area. After the path to the file we use
>   a # to denote where our file path ends and to tell the Router the name
>   of our CrisisCenter NgModule. If we look in our crisis-center.module
>   file, we can see it matches name of our exported NgModule class.

this part is missing in some blog posts, e.g.

https://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html

Comment: As per documentation, it should be enough with an `export default TestModule` in the module file, but neither that nor your solution seems to work for me.

Comment: Getting the exact same error? Worked for me right away, as soon as I followed official docs and added #ModuleClassName to the path. If your error is somewhat different, a few more details would be helpul.

Comment: you're right, sorry, it's not the same issue; I opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918992/angular2-rc5-lazy-load-routing-can%C2%B4t-find-module

Comment: @ThorstenViel you got the original error (cannot find default) because the router was looking for `export default class TestModule` -- if you look at the generated javascript, a property called `default` is added to the class you're exporting. Once you supply the #Module the router no longer needs to search for the default property...

Answer (score 9):

Modidfy your module file `./app/test/test.module.` as

```
export default class TestModule{}
```

You must have skipped the "default" keyword.

Comment: Thanks. I wish this error thrown was a bit more helpful rather than some ominous remark about "Your forgot to add the word 'default'" Great! Where?!

Comment: the compiler throws error as ' has no exported member MyNamedModule'. But if add with #MyNamedModule in routing file,it works file

Answer (score 1):

OR what else you can do is,

```
export const AdminRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'test', pathMatch: 'full'},  //<----added this


  {
    path: 'test', component: TestComponent,
    children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview' },
          { path: 'overview', component: TestOverviewComponent },
          { path: 'moredata', component: MoreDataComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: This doesn't work without my answer. Maybe I misunderstood the term 'OR' in your post. However, adding this additionally allows to nest components in the lazy loaded module, e.g. sharing a subnavigation template with it's own <router-outlet>.