# Angular2 RC5 lazy load routing can´t find module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to implement RC5 changes in my app and I'm getting some trouble when lazy loading modules in my routing.

This is the structure in my app for the affected files:

```
/app
   /components/meda/meda.module.ts
   /components/meda/meda.routing.ts
   app.routing.ts
```

And this is my app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'init', 
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: 'init', 
    loadChildren: './components/init/init.module#InitModule' 
  },
  { 
    path: 'meda', 
    loadChildren: './components/meda/meda.module#MedaModule' 
  }
];
```

and my meda.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ routing ],
})
export class MedaModule { }
```

My application loads fine into the init route because bootstrap loads InitModule, but once I try to navigate to meda I get the following

```
GET http://localhost/web/components/meda/meda.module 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems it can't find the module location. I also tried with

```
loadChildren: 'app/components/meda/meda.module#MedaModule'
```

but no luck; any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you use a workflow to create the js files in separate directories for your distribution (e.g. with gulp). You have to reference that path instead the one u are used to reference when importing in typescript.

So it is actually the path to the .js file on the server, not the ts file in your app structure, hence the 404.

Comment: but the file in the server is actually inside a bundle.app.js, how would this work then?

Comment: lazy loading is about loading implementation files you don't always need and therefore don't want to load initially. If you have the code in bundle.app.js and load this file with your app start, what do you expect to be loaded lazy, as stuff is already transported over the wire (only html files to be lazy loaded?).

Comment: ok, I get it, I somehow was thinking more about processing that just loading, but yes, that makes sense; thanks

Comment: If you mean with processing interpreting / compiling, you should have a look in the AoT section of http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html 
This will compile during build and create factory files you can serve, so you save time / performance on the client

Comment: thanks @ThorstenViel; I'm wondering, if I generate not one js bundle for my app, but many, one for each module, how would this work? I could just load the core js bundle in my index.html and then lazy load moduleA.js bundle when the user accesses that section? I'm a bit confused, because at some point I have to do the import of that moduleA bundle, will this work if I do something like this `loadChildren: 'http://localhost/web/moduleA.js#moduleA.module'`. I'm not sure I explained it properly, though...

Comment: there is IMHO a good explanation in that post https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-declarative-lazy-loading-7071d1f203ee#.8rko6bt8h that might fit your needs, around

"The loadChildren properly tells the router to fetch the ‘contacts.bundle.js’ when and only when the user navigates to ‘contacts’, then merge the two router configurations, and, finally, activate the needed components"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I changed my path according to comment of Thorsten Viel. Here is my folder structure to illustrate;

```
/wwwroot
     /app
     /scripts
```

My .ts files are under 'wwwroot/app' folder. I use 'gulp-typescript' to transpile .ts files into .js under 'wwwroot/scripts' folder. For example, if your init.module.ts path is: `wwwroot/app/components/init/init.module` and your .js file is transpiled into: `wwwroot/scripts/components/init/init.module`, you should specify like this:

```
loadChildren: 'wwwroot/scripts/components/init/init.module#InitModule'
```

It should work, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Write the path without leading . or ./ or /

```
loadChildren: 'components/init/init.module#InitModule'
```

The start point of address is the location of your html file.